# Como encontrar e alterar um padrão, sem substituir os demais elementos de uma String, com regex?

Tags: java, string, regex

Possuo um template `qualquer nome:{{UDA_numero qualquer}}` que vem  "solto" em uma `String`. Nesse `String`, pode existir "n" templates, palavras, números, etc.

O objetivo é pegar esse "**número qualquer**" do template e processar ele em uma série de operações para substituir por uma descrição que correspondente ao número. Ainda, seria necessário ignorar todo o restante dos elementos da `String` e substituir somente o template, mantendo todos os outros caracteres inalterados.

Ex:

```
     String: "teste:{{UDA_1}} teste2:{{UDA_2}} teste3:{{UDA_3}} "

     String(processada): "teste:descriacao_1 teste2:descricao_2 teste3:descricao_3
```

O problema é que essa `String` de origem pode vir de qualquer maneira possível, por exemplo:

```
    Origem: "teste:{{UDA_1}}, teste2:{{UDA_2}}, teste3:{{UDA_3}}..."
    Processado: "teste:descricao_1, teste2:descricao_2, teste3:descricao_3..."

    Origem: "teste:{{UDA_1}} \n teste2:{{UDA_2}} \n teste3:{{UDA_3}} \n"
    Processada: "teste:descricao_1 \n teste2:descricao_2 \n teste3:descricao_3 \n"

    Origem:  "teste:descricao_1teste2:descricao_2teste3:descricao_3"
    Processada: "teste:{{UDA_1}}teste2:{{UDA_2}}teste3:{{UDA_3}}"

    Origem:"teste:{{UDA_1}} abc teste2:{{UDA_2}} 123 teste3:{{UDA_3}} ^~{{}}"
    Processada:  "teste:descricao_1 abc teste2:descricao_2 123 teste3:descricao_3 ^~{{}}"

    Origem: "teste:{UDA_1}, teste2:{{UDA~~~2}}, teste3:{{3_UDA}}"
    Processada: "teste:{UDA_1}, teste2:{{UDA~~~2}}, teste3:{{3_UDA}}"
   // (Template está errado - não substitui).
```

Fazendo com que seja necessário procurar pelo padrão do template para conseguir substituir corretamente. Do jeito que eu estava tentando atualmente, era utilizando regex com a seguinte ideia:

```
         // Padrão para acessar somente os templates
         Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\{\\{(.\\w+.\\w.)\\}})+",Pattern.DOTALL);
         // String recebida
         Matcher m = p.matcher(ImportDescriptionValue);                

         // Sempre que encontrar o valor correspondente
         while (m.find()) {

             // Pega somente a parte de dentro (ex: UDA_1)           
             String uda = m.group(2);   

             // Formatar String para pegar somente o id
             String idUDA = uda.substring(uda.indexOf('_')+1);

             // **   
                ... operações com o ID

                if(encontrou descrição correspondente)

                 // Altera o atual pela descrição
                  m.replaceFirst(description);           
             }       
             else {

                 //Replace por "vazio" quando não encontrar.    
                  m.replaceFirst("");
             }
         }       

      // String processada.
      System.out.printl(m);
```

O código está errado, mas a ideia seria mais ou menos essa. Eu possuo uma solução que consegue resolver substituindo direitinho através do `split()`, mas decorrente de todas essas possíveis variações, ela é bem limitada. Por isso estava tentando utilizar outras aproximações para o problema, como o regex por exemplo.

**Minha pergunta:**

- Regex é uma boa forma de lidar com esse problema?
- Existe alguma forma boa/otimizada de resolver esse problema?

Comment: No java o método replaceAll da string suporta um regex. nem precisaria de tudo isso aí não.

Comment: Sim, mas cada template possui uma descrição diferente... se eu usasse o replaceAll() todos ficariam com a mesma descrição, não? Eu precisaria de replace() separados, para cada template ficar com a sua respectiva descrição.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que entendi, você só quer substituir `{{UDA_x}}` por `descricao_x` (sendo que "x" é um número), e vice-versa.

Se as partes `{{UDA_` e `}}` (ou `descricao_`) são sempre fixas e o que muda é só o número, basta fazer:

```
String[] textos = {
        "teste:{{UDA_1}}, teste2:{{UDA_2}}, teste3:{{UDA_3}}...",
        "teste:{{UDA_1}} \n teste2:{{UDA_2}} \n teste3:{{UDA_3}} \n",
        "teste:descricao_1teste2:descricao_2teste3:descricao_3",
        "teste:{{UDA_1}} abc teste2:{{UDA_2}} 123 teste3:{{UDA_3}} ^~{{}}",
        "teste:{UDA_1}, teste2:{{UDA~~~2}}, teste3:{{3_UDA}}" };
for (String texto : textos) {
    String processado;
    if (texto.indexOf("{{UDA_") >= 0) { // tem "{{UDA_" na String
        processado = texto.replaceAll("\\{\\{UDA_(\\d+)\\}\\}", "descricao_$1");
    } else {
        processado = texto.replaceAll("descricao_(\\d+)", "{{UDA_$1}}");
    }
    System.out.println("Origem: " + texto);
    System.out.println("Processado: " + processado);
}
```

Você não precisa usar `.` (que corresponde a [qualquer caractere](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html), e com a opção [`DOT_ALL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL), ele também corresponde a quebras de linha), e nem o [atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\w`, que corresponde a letras, números e o caractere `_`.

O ideal é que você [seja o mais específico possível](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#what_you_want). No caso, coloquei os próprios caracteres `{` (que em regex deve ser escrito como `\{`, mas como está em uma `String`, o caractere `\` é escrito como `\\`).

Depois eu uso `\\d+` (um ou mais dígitos de 0 a 9). Se os seus casos só podem ter um único dígito, basta retirar o `+`.

Além disso, eu coloco os números entre parênteses [para formar um grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). Com isso, eu consigo recuperar o respectivo valor usando a referência `$1` no segundo parâmetro do método [`replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-). Como a regex só tem um par de parênteses, o seu conteúdo (os dígitos) estará no primeiro grupo de captura, que pode ter seu valor recuperado através de `$1`.

Ou seja, `texto.replaceAll("\\{\\{UDA_(\\d+)\\}\\}", "descricao_$1")`, verifica se temos `{{UDA_`, seguido de um ou mais números, seguido de `}}`. Caso encontre, este trecho é substituído por `descricao_$1`, sendo que `$1` é o número que foi capturado anteriormente.

O mesmo vale para o segundo `replaceAll`, que faz o contrário: detecta `descricao_` seguido de um ou mais dígitos e troca por `{{UDA_$1}}`, sendo que `$1` é o número que foi capturado.

---

Esta solução é limitada a casos em que só ocorrem um dos dois (ou só tem `{{UDA_x}}`, ou só tem `descricao_x` na `String`): repare no uso de [`indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-java.lang.String-) para ver se existe `{{UDA_` na `String`.

Mas se você tiver um texto com ocorrências de ambos misturados, aí não adianta fazer um único `replaceAll`. Nesse caso, o jeito é ir percorrendo a `String` e trocando as ocorrências uma a uma:

```
String[] textos = { "teste:{{UDA_1}}, teste2:{{UDA_2}}, teste3:{{UDA_3}}...",
        "teste:{{UDA_1}} \n teste2:{{UDA_2}} \n teste3:{{UDA_3}} \n",
        "teste:descricao_1teste2:descricao_2teste3:descricao_3", 
        "teste:{{UDA_1}} abc teste2:{{UDA_2}} 123 teste3:{{UDA_3}} ^~{{}}",
        "teste:{UDA_1}, teste2:{{UDA~~~2}}, teste3:{{3_UDA}}",
        "teste:{{UDA_1}}, teste2:descricao_2" }; // string que mistura os 2 casos
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\{\\{UDA_(\\d+)\\}\\}|descricao_(\\d+)").matcher("");
for (String texto : textos) {
    matcher.reset(texto); // seta o texto no Matcher
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while (matcher.find()) {
        if (matcher.group(1) != null) { // encontrou "{{UDA_x}}"
            matcher.appendReplacement(sb, "descricao_$1");
        } else if (matcher.group(2) != null) { // encontrou "descricao_x"
            matcher.appendReplacement(sb, "{{UDA_$2}}");
        }
    }
    matcher.appendTail(sb);
    System.out.println("Origem: " + texto);
    System.out.println("Processado: " + sb.toString());
}
```

Agora a regex usa [alternância](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) (o caractere `|`), que significa **ou**. Isso quer dizer que a regex testa por `{{UDA_x}}` **ou** `descricao_x`. Em cada um, os dígitos estão entre parênteses, então cada um forma um grupo de captura.

Aí basta testar qual dos grupos foi capturado. Se foi o grupo 1, quer dizer que a regex encontrou uma ocorrência de `{{UDA_x}}`, e basta trocar por `descricao_$1`. Se foi o grupo 2, quer dizer que foi encontrado `descricao_x`, e basta trocar por `{{UDA_$2}}` (repare que usei `$2`, pois agora os dígitos estão no segundo grupo de captura - já que é o segundo par de parênteses da regex).

---

Se quiser, você ainda pode verificar se o que tem antes do template é "um nome seguido de dois pontos":

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\w+:)(?:\\{\\{UDA_(\\d+)\\}\\}|descricao_(\\d+))").matcher("");
```

Eu uso um [*lookbehind*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), que só verifica se algo existe antes, mas esse algo não faz parte do *match*, e por isso não é substituído. No caso, o *lookbehind* é `(?<=\\w+:)` (um ou mais letras/números/`_`, seguido de dois pontos).

Em seguida eu agrupo o restante da regex entre parênteses, mas para que ele não se torne um grupo de captura (e interfira com os grupos 1 e 2 já existentes), eu uso `(?:`, o que transforma os parênteses em um [grupo de não-captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap) (ou seja, este par de parênteses não cria as variáveis especiais, como `$1` e `$2`). Assim o restante do código pode permanecer o mesmo, sem precisar mudar o número dos grupos.

Ou seja, se você testar esta regex com a string `"teste:{{UDA_1}}, teste2:descricao_2, {{UDA_3}}"`, o trecho `{{UDA_3}}` não será substituído, pois não tem um nome (uma ou mais letras, números ou `_`) seguido de `:` imediatamente antes dele.

Se quiser ser mais específico, pode trocar o `\\w+` por algo como `[a-zA-Z]+` (uma ou mais letras de `a` a `z`, maiúsculas ou minúsculas). Adapte de acordo com o que você precisar.